# How to get all generated ID's while insert bulk rows

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

```
String sql = "YOUR INSERT STATEMENT HERE";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ps.execute();

ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
int generatedKey = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    int generatedKey = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.println("Inserted record ID: " + generatedKey);
}
```

Above statement returning only last inserted row ID only.

How to get All generated ID's while inserting bulk values ?

Comment: How are you inserting bulk values? `executeBatch()` or multiple `VALUES` in `INSERT`?

Comment: Also, what is the database and JDBC driver you are using.

Comment: If I am right, at the moment you are getting output as the one you inserted and not all the id's. You want to insert a records and there after you want to retrieve all the id's from the database ?

Comment: Yes, inserting multiple VALUES in INSERT.
I am using jdbc:sqlite driver.
I would like to get Inserted all row ID's while bulk insert records.

Comment: So how many rows does your INSERT statement insert? If you only insert one row with that, then getGeneratedKeys() will obviously only return one ID

Comment: I am inserting 400 rows, but returning last index ID only, not all row ID's
I need all inserted row ID's